# Give line breaks while running seeder through artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

How can I give line breaks through the php's `echo` command to give meaningful status messages during the script's run.

I have tried `echo` with `/n` but to no avail, I have to use spaces to compensate which is very time consuming. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Artisan output commands:

```
$this->info('Display this on the screen');
...
$this->error('Something went wrong!');
```

You can read more about it [here on the Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands)

Comment: I am using the code in the DatabaseSeeder which gives undefined method error, how can i use it here?

Comment: I moved the code to a new command, apparently one had to extend the class from Command.